# Errors occurs when accessing unordered_map by [] operator

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, unordered-map

I stumbled upon a strange problem with an unordered_map.

First I generated an `unordered_map<string, Person>` and inserted a record ("Bob", Person(1, "Bob")) into the table. Then I tried to access the record by using the [] operator with key "Bob" and an error happened.

This is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<unordered_map>
using namespace std;

class Person
{
    public:
        int play;
        string name;
        Person(int p, string n):play(p), name(n) {}
};

int main()
{
    unordered_map<string,Person> test;
    test.insert(std::make_pair("haha",Person(1,"haha")));
    cout<<test["haha"].name<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Errors occur when I compile the code with "g++ -S hash.cpp"
Output:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/unordered_map:41:0,
                 from hash.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/7/tuple: In instantiation of ‘std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::tuple<_Args1 ...>&, std::tuple<_Args2 ...>&, std::_Index_tuple<_Indexes1 ...>, std::_Index_tuple<_Indexes2 ...>) [with _Args1 = {std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&}; long unsigned int ..._Indexes1 = {0}; _Args2 = {}; long unsigned int ..._Indexes2 = {}; _T1 = const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _T2 = Person]’:
/usr/include/c++/7/tuple:1641:63:   required from ‘std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::piecewise_construct_t, std::tuple<_Args1 ...>, std::tuple<_Args2 ...>) [with _Args1 = {std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&}; _Args2 = {}; _T1 = const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _T2 = Person]’
/usr/include/c++/7/ext/new_allocator.h:136:4:   required from ‘void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, Person>; _Args = {const std::piecewise_construct_t&, std::tuple<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&>, std::tuple<>}; _Tp = std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, Person>]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/alloc_traits.h:475:4:   required from ‘static void std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_CharT> >::construct(std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_CharT> >::allocator_type&, _Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, Person>; _Args = {const std::piecewise_construct_t&, std::tuple<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&>, std::tuple<>}; _Tp = std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, Person>; std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_CharT> >::allocator_type = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, Person> >]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/hashtable_policy.h:2066:37:   required from ‘std::__detail::_Hashtable_alloc<_NodeAlloc>::__node_type* std::__detail::_Hashtable_alloc<_NodeAlloc>::_M_allocate_node(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {const std::piecewise_construct_t&, std::tuple<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&>, std::tuple<>}; _NodeAlloc = std::allocator<std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, Person>, true> >; std::__detail::_Hashtable_alloc<_NodeAlloc>::__node_type = std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, Person>, true>]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/hashtable_policy.h:750:8:   required from ‘std::__detail::_Map_base<_Key, _Pair, _Alloc, std::__detail::_Select1st, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits, true>::mapped_type& std::__detail::_Map_base<_Key, _Pair, _Alloc, std::__detail::_Select1st, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits, true>::operator[](std::__detail::_Map_base<_Key, _Pair, _Alloc, std::__detail::_Select1st, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits, true>::key_type&&) [with _Key = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Pair = std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, Person>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, Person> >; _Equal = std::equal_to<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _H1 = std::hash<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _H2 = std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing; _Hash = std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash; _RehashPolicy = std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy; _Traits = std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, false, true>; std::__detail::_Map_base<_Key, _Pair, _Alloc, std::__detail::_Select1st, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits, true>::mapped_type = Person; std::__detail::_Map_base<_Key, _Pair, _Alloc, std::__detail::_Select1st, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits, true>::key_type = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/unordered_map.h:980:20:   required from ‘std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::mapped_type& std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::operator[](std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::key_type&&) [with _Key = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Tp = Person; _Hash = std::hash<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Pred = std::equal_to<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, Person> >; std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::mapped_type = Person; std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::key_type = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’
hash.cpp:17:19:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/tuple:1652:70: error: no matching function for call to ‘Person::Person()’
         second(std::forward<_Args2>(std::get<_Indexes2>(__tuple2))...)
                                                                      ^
hash.cpp:10:3: note: candidate: Person::Person(int, std::__cxx11::string)
   Person(int p, string n):play(p), name(n) {}
   ^~~~~~
hash.cpp:10:3: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
hash.cpp:5:7: note: candidate: Person::Person(const Person&)
 class Person
       ^~~~~~
hash.cpp:5:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
hash.cpp:5:7: note: candidate: Person::Person(Person&&)
hash.cpp:5:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

I had inserted the record but the map seemed to be unaware of this and tried to insert the record again.

So how does the g++ compiler process the [] operator?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to include the string header, and you need a default constructor for Person. `test["haha"].name` could need to construct an object, and without a default constructor you have a problem. You can see this in the error here: `no matching function for call to ‘Person::Person()`

Comment: Done. Thanks for your help. I have not considered the possible demand of [] operator. This is really a matter of concern

Comment: I cannot but downvote this post, as the compiler clearly states the problem, yet you ask this on SO.

Comment: Thanks. I mistakenly ignored the rule and thought my code won't construct a new Person object, which is the root cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers given are correct. I just want to add why the default constructor is not provided by the compiler in this case:

From online [cpp reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor)

> If **no** user-declared constructors of any kind are provided for a class type (struct, class, or union), the compiler will always declare a default constructor as an inline public member of its class.

But if user-declared constructors of any kind are provided, the compiler will **not** generate a default constructor.

> If some user-declared constructors are present, the user may still force the automatic generation of a default constructor by the compiler that would be implicitly-declared otherwise with the keyword default. (since C++11)

So you can add the following line to the code in the public section of the class and your code will work as intended:

```
Person() = default;
```

Comment: very useful and insightful. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 5):

Mapped type of unordered_map must be DefaultConstructible under `operator[]`. I.e. Person() must have a default constructor, if you want to be able to use `operator[]`.

As an alternative, use at():

```
int main() 
{ 
 std::unordered_map<string,Person> test;
 test.insert(std::make_pair("haha",Person(1,"haha")));
 std::cout<<test.at("haha").name<<'\n';
 return 0; 
}
```

The mapped type has to be DefaultConstructible  because `operator[]` should be able to create missing entries. The data in new entries is  default constructed .

Comment: Yes, I ignored the rule and got the complaint from the compiler. Thanks.

Comment: @ronald you can get away from implementing a default constructor by using insert, emplace, find, and at(), instead of []

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not with [] operator. Actual problem is that when the compiler executes the following line:

```
cout<<test["haha"].name<<endl;
```

It tries to create an object of type Person using it's **default constructor**. Since default constructor is not defined, it throws an error.

The following code will work fine. I have just added a default constructor.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<unordered_map>
using namespace std;

class Person
{
    public:
        int play;
        string name;
        Person(){}     //Add default constructor 
        Person(int p, string n):play(p), name(n) {}
};

int main()
{
    unordered_map<string,Person> test;
    test.insert(std::make_pair("haha",Person(1,"haha")));
    cout<<test["haha"].name<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks :). A very important lesson.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the comments and another answer, [`unordered_map<>::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at) **may** need to create an object: if none is found for the key, it inserts a default constructed element and returns that.

If that is not what you want, you may simply *attempt* to find an element and only use it if present:

```
auto it = map.find("haha");
if(it != map.end()) {
    cout << it->second.name;
}
```

Btw, internally the `unordered_map` holds as `value_type` a `std::pair<key,Person>`. Thus, if you hash by name (as you do), the `Person`'s name is stored twice. One possible way to avoid this is the following construction:

```
struct personData
{
    int play; // etc
};

using personMap = unordered_map<string,personData>;
using person = personMap::value_type;
```

The only inconvenience is that you have to access the data like `play` via `person::second.play`. One way to fix that is to define

```
struct person : private personMap::value_type
{
     using base = personMap::value_type;
     // must not add new data members to avoid slicing
     personData& data() { return base.second; }
     personData const& data() const { return base.second; }
     int play() const { return data().play; }
     string const&name() const { return base.first; }
};

auto fred = static_cast<person&>(map["fred"]);
```

Comment: Yes, I had noticed the rule "if none is found for the key, it inserts a default constructed element and returns that" of unordered_map. But I thought my program could find the key and so I ignored the necessary check from the compiler, which was the root cause. Thanks. An important lesson.